# Download instead of visit resource on site (mod rewrite issue)

Tags: html, forms, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a website that adds a trailing `/` onto every URL, but I've got a file I want to download with a regular form using regular html. When I add the URL of the item to download .jar file to the form action: `action="/resources/app.jar"` a slash gets added on the end and it gets treated like a directory.

Is there anyway I can specifically set it to download without messing around with my url redirects?

If it makes it easier would it be possible to just remove the trailing slashes for any url that ends in `.zip/` in the URL bar?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to exclude types of urls from having a slash appended to them. If you add slashes to your urls, your entire site has probably 'pretty urls', so without extensions. Files with extensions should probably be downloaded:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !([^/]+)\.([^/]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
```

If you want to exclude a specific directory instead, for example the directory "downloads" that contains all the downloads, you can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/path/to/downloads/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]
```

If needed, make sure that the rule does not match internally rewritten urls.